# Gensim Phrase model parameters (threshold)

Tags: model, gensim, threshold, phrase

Could someone please explain to me what does the parameter threshold do in the Phrase model of Gensim? and how to choose it when it comes to train a dataset that contains a lot of data?
I searched among many tutorials but still didn't get a clear idea about it
thank you

Answer (score 2):

As a fairly crude statistical method of finding interesting word-pairs, the choice of optimal parameters is simply a matter of what works better for your purposes.

Try values smaller & larger than the default, and test the resulting phrases against some repeatable quality evaluation on your real end-goal. Choose the value that scores best.

Beware that because this method is completely oblivious to things like grammar, the phrases created will not reliably match human understanding of logical word-groupings. At any set of tuned parameters, it will create some unwanted phrases, and miss others you'd consider useful.

Thus, its tokenized-text output typically isn't appropriate for display to end-user, even though it can be useful input for other analysis steps, like a classifier or document-similarity calculation.